# How to display shapefile without map in Android?

Tags: shapefile, android

I have a shapefile which has some building data and I want to display that building structure in Android I have checked nutiteq SDK but they are providing shp file on map not only shapefile can I load only shapefile without map layer?

Comment: Have you tried using nutiteq and simply not setting a basemap? Maybe that will work.

Comment: I have tried using https://github.com/nutiteq/hellomap3d/wiki/Ogr-layer and set as a base layer using mapView.getLayers().setBaseLayer(ogrLayer); but this does not show any data

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the QGIS for Android? It is still in a rather early developement stage, but it should do the trick.
You can find it here: http://hub.qgis.org/projects/android-qgis